# Alter other fields based on one field input with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a form that has two options: Return and Exchange.
If Return is selected, the lower fields need to become "***n/a***" as values. If Exchange is selected the values input need to remain.

This doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
  $exchname = addslashes($_POST["exchname"]);
  $exchsize = addslashes($_POST["exchsize"]);

  if($returntype = "return"){
     $exchname = "n/a";
     $exchsize = "n/a";
  }
```

Any pointers on what's going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `addslashes()`?

Comment: This would always be truthy: `if($returntype = "return"){` It should be: `if($returntype == "return"){` with 2 `=` signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use two = like this

```
if($returntype == 'return')
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to make sense but I've just put that in and it still ignores the IF statement and either inputs nothing or whatever was typed into the other fields when Return was selected. I may just resort to using jQuery to swap the lower parts of the form on selection.

Comment: I realized I put the IF statement after the add to database line. It works now thanks!